# LPT,COM переходники на USB

Tags: usb, железо, com-порт, lpt

Будет ли видеть LPT или COM порт планшет если на него установить переходник с USB на COM  или LPT?

Answer (score 1):

1. на планшете должен быть OTG
2. в ОС планшета должны быть драйвера на данный переходник

например андроид (вернее линукс под которым он работает) понимает COM-порты с контроллерами компании FTDI